# LLBLGen - How to execute an IRetrievalQuery

Tags: c#, llblgenpro

I am trying to execute an IRetrievalQuery using the `execute()` method but I am getting the error "No connection is present. Cannot execute command." The documentation tells that I need to open a connection but I am not sure how. What should I do to execute my query ? Any ideas ? I am using LLBLGen version 2.6.

Code:

```
IRetrievalQuery query = RetrievalProcedures.GetLlmBudgetGetDepTotalCancelledCallAsQuery(month, BudgetUtils.CurrentTerm(), department);

DataTable data = new DataTable();
data.Load(query.Execute(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection)); // execute fails
```

Comment: Show your code first..

Comment: @SonerGönül please see the edit. All I really want is to execute the query and fill its result into a DataTable

Comment: I'm not too much familiar with it but you can check these links: https://llblgen.com/tinyforum/Messages.aspx?ThreadID=21544 and http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2705/Using-a-LLBLGen-generated-data-access-tier Also ask it on https://llblgen.com/tinyforum

Comment: Thanks @SonerGönül I will have a look

Answer (score 0):

I asked it on LLBLGEN form and this is the [answer](http://www.llblgen.com/TinyForum/Messages.aspx?ThreadID=22389) I got. I basically needed something like below:

```
using( DataAccessAdapter adapter = new DataAccessAdapter() )
{
    IDataReader reader = adapter.FetchDataReader( 
        RetrievalProcedures.GetCustOrdersOrdersCallAsQuery( "CHOPS" ), 
        CommandBehavior.CloseConnection );
    while( reader.Read() )
    {
        Console.WriteLine( "Row: {0} | {1} | {2} | {3} |", reader.GetValue( 0 ), 
            reader.GetValue( 1 ), reader.GetValue( 2 ), reader.GetValue( 3 ) );
    }
    // close reader, will also close connection
    reader.Close();
}
```

The `IDataReader` instance in the example can also be used to load the data into a DataTable using its `Load` method.

Comment: Regarding the load method - it is the load method on the DataTable as in:
`DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Load(myIDataReader);`